# OP_REQUIRES failed Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 5. But input(1) is a vector of size 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I have a TF Estimator model with code as follows : 
'''

```
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, model_dir=outputdir)


def batchGen(features, labels):      
    num = 0
    for i in itertools.count(0):   
        if(num < len(features)):
           yield features[i], labels[i]
           num+=1 
        else:
           break  


def newFeatureFunc(x):
  x = x.decode("utf-8") 
  outT = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x, maxlen)
  outT = outT.astype(np.float32)
  return outT

def newLabelFunc(y):
    outT = utils.to_categorical(y, nb_classes)
    return outT

def train_fn_custom(features, labels, batch_size): 
    genSet = lambda : batchGen(features,labels)
    dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(genSet,(tf.string, tf.float32),(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([])))

    def _preprocess_function(features, labels):      
        output1 = tf.py_func(newFeatureFunc, [features], tf.float32)       
        output1.set_shape([,maxlen])        
        output2 = tf.py_func(newLabelFunc, [labels], tf.float32)
        output2.set_shape([,nb_classes])
        return output1, output2

    dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess_function)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(9)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

batch_size = 1
customTrain = lambda:train_fn_custom(X1, y_train, batch_size)
estimator_model.train(input_fn=customTrain, steps=100)
```

'''

This produces the error

> OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:157 : Invalid argument: transpose  expects a vector of size 5. But input(1) is a vector of size 4

I am unable to point to the location of code causing this error and what it means in the context of my estimator. Can someone please provide some insights?